# How can I get codec information for a quicktime video in Objective C/Cocoa? (Without FFMPEG)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video, codec

Hello and thanks for your time,
I am creating an application that moves video files around to be processed by other applications. In the past, I have used mediainfo, and ffmpeg, in ruby to obtain codec information about each file. I would however like to transfer all of this into one beautiful cocoa app. I have searched and searched and still can't find a solution (without using ffmpeg) on how to do this. I am basically looking for the exact same info you get in the quicktime video inspector window (apple + i). 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, sample code, even more so.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Spotlight Queries (NSMetadataQuery), like the `mdls` command do :

```
> mdls ~/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/iTunes\ U/WWDC\ 2011\ Session\ Videos\ -\ HD/1-01\ Apple\ Platforms\ Kickoff.m4v 
kMDItemAudioBitRate            = 103
kMDItemAudioChannelCount       = 2
kMDItemCodecs                  = (
    AAC,
    "H.264"
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2011-07-01 15:49:56 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2011-07-01 16:13:39 +0000
kMDItemContentType             = "com.apple.m4v-video"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "com.apple.m4v-video",
    "public.movie",
    "public.audiovisual-content",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded               = 2011-07-01 16:13:39 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName             = "1-01 Apple Platforms Kickoff.m4v"
kMDItemDurationSeconds         = 2787.754421087755
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = 2011-07-01 16:13:39 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = 2011-07-01 15:49:56 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = "hook"
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = 0
kMDItemFSLabel                 = 0
kMDItemFSName                  = "1-01 Apple Platforms Kickoff.m4v
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = 1147843844
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = 502
kMDItemFSSize                  = 1147843844
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemKind                    = "Video Media"
kMDItemLogicalSize             = 1147843844
kMDItemMediaTypes              = (
    Sound,
    Video
)
kMDItemPhysicalSize            = 1147846656
kMDItemPixelHeight             = 540
kMDItemPixelWidth              = 958
kMDItemProfileName             = "HD (1-1-1)"
kMDItemStreamable              = 0
kMDItemTotalBitRate            = 3287
kMDItemVideoBitRate            = 3184
```

Or you can check the AVFoundation framework.

Sample code:

```
 -(NSDictionary *) metadataForFileAtPath:(NSString *) path {
    NSURL *url = [[[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:path] autorelease];

    MDItemRef itemRef = MDItemCreateWithURL(NULL, (CFURLRef)url);
    NSArray *attributeNames = (NSArray *)MDItemCopyAttributeNames(itemRef);
    NSDictionary *attributes = (NSDictionary *) MDItemCopyAttributes(itemRef, (CFArrayRef) attributeNames);
    CFRelease(itemRef);

    // probably it is leaking memory (attributeNames and attributes), better check with Instruments

    return attributes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, the mdls command returns exactly what I need. However to do this in cocoa I would need to use "system()" or "NSTask" which I am trying to avoid. I googled around for a few hours this morning trying to figure out how to return the same type of data using NSMetadataQuery but was un able to figure it out. Seems it searches for files based on metadata info, but I am trying to extract metadata info from a specific file. Can you provide a code sample of how this might work? Can anyone else suggest a better way?

Comment: Hello Adam, I've just added a few lines of code to do the same as the `mdls` command.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I have implemented your code but get the following errors:      `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_MDItemCreateWithURL", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_MDItemCopyAttributeNames", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_MDItemCopyAttributes", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: `Ld /Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMD-ehrvnxokboahvhdwhawqssbvpqhy/Build/Products/Debug/TestMD normal x86_64 cd /Users/myusername/Desktop/TestMD setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    /Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -L/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMD-ehrvnxokboahvhdwhawqssbvpqhy/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/myusername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestMD-ehrvnxokboahvhdwhawqssbvpqhy/Build/Products/Debug -filelist`

Comment: Marcelo, I really appreciate your help with this. Once I added the CoreServices.framework everything worked great. I do seem to be having issues returning metadata on mounted volumes. Do you have any additional insight on how I may be able to get that to work? Other than that this is a great answer and a great solution to my needs!

Comment: Hmm, spotlight metadata don't work with all mounted volumes. Are you trying with a FTP/NFS volume?

Comment: I was mounting the drive using AFP. I also tested an SMB mount to no avail.

Comment: Probably the AFP/SMB share wasn't indexed by Spotlight. In this case, you will need to use the AVFoundation framework, sorry.

Comment: A bit simpler: `MDItemRef itemRef = MDItemCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,(CFStringRef)path);` (without NSURL)