# Get the real "last opened" date?

Tags: macos, cocoa, file-io

The following code is working. It's expected to return the app last launch date, but...

```
// e.g. entryPath = @"/Applications/Evernote.app"

struct stat output;
int ret = stat([entryPath fileSystemRepresentation], &output);
if (ret == 0)
{
    struct timespec accessTime = output.st_atimespec;
    NSDate * date1 = [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:accessTime.tv_sec]
            dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    // and the 10.6+ version: (the result was always the same for me)
    NSDate * date2 = [[[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:entryPath]
            resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLContentAccessDateKey]
                            error:nil]
            objectForKey:NSURLContentAccessDateKey]
            dateWithCalendarFormat:nil timeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
}
```

It returns very strange dates, usually near 3:00-3:30 AM, today or yesterday, when I was actually sleeping. But after that, I click "Get Info" in Finder, and it shows the real last launch date (which is usually less than `date1` and `date2`, but can be also equal). How to get it programmatically?
[image: Finder get info: Last opened date]

Comment: Looks like this comes from Spotlight, though I'm not sure how to obtain the value programmatically. The key is `kMDItemLastUsedDate`.

Comment: @noa: You'd use `MDItemCreateWithURL`. Feel free to make that an answer.

Comment: @noa: In your answer, you may use [the sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6726872/1289683). :) Thanks so much! Spotlight features are awesome! P.S. Found [Spotlight Metadata Attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1) explanation.